# Should I Dispose Object Passed Through Constructor If Other Constructors Create It?

Tags: c#, class, constructor, dispose

Given the following code, should I only dispose `foo` when it was created by within the `Bar` class? Or should I always dispose `foo` even when it was passed to a constructor? I'm thinking I should probably add another private variable to keep track of whether `Bar` created `foo` or whether it was passed to the `Bar( Foo foo )` constructor, and only dispose of `foo` when it was created by the `public Bar( string name )` constructor.

```
public class Bar: IDisposable
{
    private Foo foo = null;

    public Bar( string name )
    {
        this.foo = new Foo(name);
    }
    public Bar( Foo foo )
    {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
    protected virtual void Dispose( bool disposing )
    {
        if( disposed )
            return;
        if( disposing )
            foo.Dispose();
        this.disposed = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Title sucks, I know. Best I could word it. Please change if you can improve.

Comment: That object doesn't have a finalizer, so there's no need to suppress the [non-existant] finalizer

Comment: The Framework faced this problem, and provided an optional boolean parameter to control whether ownership is taken over or the object is left alive.  See [StreamWriter Constructor (Stream, Encoding, Int32, Boolean)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712853.aspx)  In fact, your case is exactly analogous, where `Bar` is `StreamWriter`, `Foo` is `Stream`, and `Bar` can also automatically create the stream if given a filename.

Comment: It's going to depend on context, what the actual meaning of these objects are, how they're used, whether or not a caller is likely to want to continue using it after providing it to this object, or even use it in any other context, etc.

Comment: @BenVoigt In that one instance, yet.  And yet most other situations where an `IDisposable` object is provided to an object it does one or the other, not both.  That was an unusual context in that both made sense often enough for it to need to provide that option.  It's certainly not the norm.

Comment: Going with @BenVoigt's suggestion to pass a Boolean on the constructor to leave it open or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're correct in your thinking.

If you're passed an instance of `Foo` from elsewhere, and dispose of it yourself, you might break code still consuming the `Foo`. If you create an instance of `Foo` but don't dispose of it, you'll hang on to the memory it consumes unnecessarily long.

So, your best option is to track whether you created the instance yourself and dispose of it if so. (You could also allow the caller to specify the behaviour, as has been mentioned in the comments.)

(Alternatively, you *could* not do anything, which will be more inefficient but will at least not break anything. The only solution that is likely to actively break something is if you dispose of the instance that's been passed in from elsewhere.)

Comment: Often when providing a disposable object to another object like this you will be passing ownership of that disposable object over.  It's not *always* the case, but it's quite often the case, and, so long as that's make clear in the documentation, disposing of the object would then be appropriate.  This is typically done in cases where using the object consumes it, leaving it unusable even if not disposed.  Conversely, if it makes sense for the caller to maintain ownership, that means that they would simply be responsible for disposing of it, not that it wouldn't get disposed.